# Problem with mysql2 adapter "group" statement when writing queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run the following query in ruby:

```
Transaction.all(:select => "created_at, SUM(amount) amount", :group => "created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')", :order => 'created_at')
```

I get the following error in mysql2 (Works in mysql):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION created_at.strftime does not exist:
```

What I need is to group all the transaction on date(without the time). 
I could probably rewrite the statement, are there anyone who can help my with this?
Thanks!

Comment: `strftime` is a Ruby method, the argument for `:group` needs to be an SQL snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`DATE` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) that does what you want.

```
# mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
#        -> '2003-12-31'
#
# used in your query:

Transaction.all(
  :select => "created_at, SUM(amount) amount",
  :group => "DATE(created_at)",
  :order => "created_at")
```